# Using clang-format with c++20 concepts

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, clang-format

I have looked at the clang-format style options https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html but don't see any reference to c++ concepts and requires clauses.  Normally I can configure clang-format to do what I want but I can't figure out how to get it to handle my concepts and requires clauses nicely:

1. Currently clang-format does this to my concepts:

```cpp
template <typename F, typename P, typename T>
concept Accumulate_Fn = Parser<P>&& std::invocable<F, T, parser_t<P>>&&
    std::same_as<T, std::invoke_result_t<F, T, parser_t<P>>>;
```

But I would like to put each one constraint on its own line (as it does for function arguments that get too long) so that the result would look like:

```cpp
template <typename F, typename P, typename T>
concept Accumulate_Fn = Parser<P> &&
                        std::invocable<F, T, parser_t<P>> &&
                        std::same_as<T, std::invoke_result_t<F, T, parser_t<P>>>;
```

2. For a function with a requires clause, clang-format currently gives me:

```cpp
template <Parser P1, Parser P2, typename T, Accumulate_Fn<P1, parser_t<P1>> F>
requires std::same_as<T, parser_t<P1>> constexpr Parser auto
separated_by(P1&& p1, P2&& p2, T&& init, F&& f)
```

But I would like something much closer to :

```cpp
template <Parser P1, Parser P2, typename T, Accumulate_Fn<P1, parser_t<P1>> F>
requires std::same_as<T, parser_t<P1>> 
constexpr Parser auto separated_by(P1&& p1, P2&& p2, T&& init, F&& f)
```

Are there any magical options that will make that work?  I'm currently on clang-format 10.0.

Comment: clang-format only allows including rules used in extant coding standards. Since nowadays everybody uses clang-format, there's a chicken-and-egg problem. For the same reason there is e.g. no way to format if-with-initializer in a controlled way (I asked about that here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67697966/can-clang-format-format-if-with-initializer-c17).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of Jul/20, Concepts are not properly supported by `clang-format`. There is an [open issue](https://reviews.llvm.org/D79773) in LLVM tracker.

Comment: Thanks for linking to the issue.  I'll be keeping an eye on it.

Comment: I wonder when Concepts will be supported.

Comment: clang-format v15 fixes these issues with option `RequiresClausePosition: OwnLine`